# Fire Trigger Only After All Items have been Inserted in the Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ssms

We have table that holds each item on an order in a separate row. In basic terms, I want to use a trigger that fires when an order is entered to set a field for each item to either A if the total value of the order is >= $50 and set it to B if it's less than that. I've written the trigger and it works but only on each item.

For example, item 1 is $75 and item 2 is $25. Total of the order is $100 so I want the trigger to set both items to A. However, the trigger is working on each separately item 1 is being set to A and item 2 is being set to B.

Is it possible to make the trigger work on the entire order instead of each line item separately? If so, how? If not, is there another method I can use to accomplish this?

This is simplified version of my trigger so far:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Disposition 
ON order_line 
FOR UPDATE
AS

IF (@@rowcount = 0)
    RETURN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @order_min int

SET @order_min = (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(item_price) order_min
                  FROM order_line ol 
                  INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.order_no = o.order_no
                                                        
IF @order_min >= 50
BEGIN
    UPDATE order_line 
    SET disposition = 'A'
    FROM inserted
    INNER JOIN order_line ON inserted.order_no = order_line.order_no 
                          AND inserted.item = order_line.item
    WHERE order_line.order_no = inserted.order_no
      AND inserted.line_no = order_line.line_no

    RETURN
END
ELSE IF @order_min < 50
BEGIN
    UPDATE order_line 
    SET disposition = 'B'
    FROM inserted
    INNER JOIN order_line ON inserted.order_no = order_line.order_no 
                          AND inserted.item = order_line.item
    WHERE order_line.order_no = inserted.order_no
      AND inserted.line_no = order_line.line_no

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Have the client application insert all of the rows into `order_line` at once instead of one a time. It can build the desired lines in the application and then pass the set to the database as a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: `distinct SUM(item_price)` makes little sense, since you sum over the whole set you can only ever get one value. I would also expect an error here: do you want to sum from `inserted` or from `order_line`? Please add sample data to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. Also please show how you are updating the table. Additionally, "I want to use a trigger that fires when an order is entered" sounds like an insert rather than an update

Comment: This trigger is flawed in multiple ways, by using an intermediate variable you're assuming only 1 order will ever be inserted at a time, but what if there were several, triggers should *always* be written to operate on a set of rows, this should be a *single* update statement.

Comment: Aside: It looks like the `'A'`/`'B'` status is really a feature of an _order_, not an _order line_. It depends on all of the order lines in the order, quantities and prices. That implies that if _any_ of those change that the status ought to be recalculated and updated as needed. (Curious that there doesn't appear to be a _quantity_ since you just sum `item_price`. Unless that is your name for the _extended price_ taking into account unit price, quantity, surcharges, discounts, ... .)

Comment: I agree, this is an `order` relation, not an `order_line` relation. But I'm not even sure why you want to store this information at all. Instead, you should create a query or view that calculates and shows this to you.